# HtmlAgilityPack create node from text

Tags: html, replace, html-agility-pack

Let's assume I have this

```
<div>
    <p>Bla bla bla specialword bla bla bla</p>
    <p>Bla bla bla bla bla specialword</p>
</div>
```

I want to replace the word `specialword` from my html with a node, for example `<b>specialword</b>`. This is easy using string replacement, but I want to use the Html Agility Pack features.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think HtmlAgilityPack has that feature. You might just have to do the string replacement.

Comment: I'd first create a document from the HTML snippet, then search for the text nodes whose text contain the word needed, and then replace the word with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlNode has a method called ReplaceChild, should do the trick.
**Updated after comment**

HtmlAgilityPack has no reason to have that ability as it is pure string manipulation, if I'm reading you correctly, and .NET does that fine as-is :

```
HtmlNode div = doc.CreateElement("div");
div.InnerHtml = Regex.Replace("(.*?)specialword(.*?)","{1}<b>specialword</b>{2}");
```

Then find the node and do a replace from it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace savepage
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //...
       // using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
       // {
        string[] nametag = { "//img", "//div", "//p", "//li", "//pre", "//span", "//ul" };
        Console.WriteLine("Enter address site:"); 
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(Console.ReadLine()); // get address site
       // Console.WriteLine("Enter Tag:"); 

            // all <td> tags in the document
        Console.WriteLine("0=img ,1=div,2=p,3=li,4=pre,5=span,6=ul");
        string name = nametag[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) ]; //get list array
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        //  foreach (HtmlNode span in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span"))

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\WriteLines2.txt"))
        {

            foreach (HtmlNode tag in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(name))
            {
                //  HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes[@"src"];
                // Console.WriteLine(img.InnerText);
                Console.WriteLine(tag.InnerText);
                file.WriteLine(tag.InnerText);
                //doc.Save(@"c:\majid.txt");
            }
        }

            Console.ReadKey();


      //  }
    }
}
```

}